# PHP. How to make a button redirect with a link between tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I make a redirect button with the following structure. The inside of the button is a link, but doesn't redirect to the link. The button doesn't respond when a link is between a button tag.  I can't delete or change the `<a>` object `<a>`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right btnCreateUser"
        style="text-decoration: none"><a>...</a></button>
```

Comment: your question is really vague. Do you want this? <a href="#">this link doesnt go anywhere</a>

Comment: it doesn't, I update my question

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `<a>` element:

```
<a href="link.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right btnCreateUser">
  ...
</a>
```

Assigning the `btn` class to the `<a>` element, this link will look like a button.

Check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).